# Migrate ASP.Net Website to Azure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, azure

I have an ASP.NET in VB code base that if I open in Visual Studio as an existing website works and tests just fine.

I have followed many tutorials for porting this over to Azure:

-Tried create new Azure project add a webrole and drag and drop project files into the new webrole, but I get about 300 reference/missing stuff/etc errors

-I have also tried creating an azure project under the website solution but the option to add the website to the webrole by clicking "web role project in solution" is disabled/grayed out

I have been able to make the configuration files and compile through the command line but this does not work with visual studio so I am unable to test before deploying into staging

Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't a real answer, but have you thought about trying out AppHarbor (http://appharbor.com/). All you need to do is set up Mercurial or Git and then push code to deploy. Makes this process quite a bit easier.

Comment: Take a look at the Azure Websites Migration Assistant - see http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/28/introducing-azure-websites-migration-assistant/

Answer (score 0):

So many things could go wrong here.

First off , make sure you create a cloud application in VB.net and not in c# ;) and use the correct .net framework.

I wouldn't suggest to just drag & drop the files into a new webrole. 
I thing I do the most is just create an cloud application and add no roles at all.

After the application is created, right click on the Solution and 'Add Existing Project'.
This way all the references dll's should come straight with it. You might want to watch out with dll's from class library's you use. You might have to add them manually.

The next thing you should look at is your web.config. 
The web.config needs some basic stuff. 
For the exact things you need I suggest you just make add a new basic webrole and copy the web.config from there and then delete the webrole ofc.

Next time you should do is add a Role and click Web Role project in solution.

Rebuild and check your other errors and try to fix them :)